# Improving Newton's method to solve a nonlinear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

When solving $f(x)=0$ we can use Newton's method iteration $x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{ f(x_k) }{f'(x_k)} $.  What if we replace $f'(x_k)$ by a constant say $\alpha$:

$$ x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{ f(x_k) }{\alpha} $$

Will this scheme always be locally convergent? If so, what is convergence rate?

#### try

if maybe see this as fixed-point iteration by making $g(x) = x- \frac{f(x) }{\alpha}$, then $g'(x) = 1 - \frac{f'(x) }{\alpha} $. If $x^*$ is the root, then $|g'(x^*)| = |1 - \frac{ f'(x^*) }{\alpha} |<1$

So $\alpha < f'(x^*) $ gives locally convergence. how can we find convergence rate?

Comment: You have essentially all written down, convergence is linear with factor about $|1-\frac{f(x^*)}{α}|$.

Comment: Agreeing with @LutzL, may I add that, in the old time (mine !), $\alpha=f'(x_0)$ was a standard method.

Comment: It is the simplified Newton method. It is used, among others, in the proof of the implicit function theorem and for the corrector in implicit numerical methods for ODE.